# Isolation of Input signal and supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage, operational-amplifier, ground, isolation

I have this op-amp like circuit. Where the input signal is an 70V High voltage signal and the power supply is 3.3V voltage signal to a MCU GPIO.

My question is how should I isolate the high voltage signal from the low voltage op-amp supply?

Also, the output is going to an ADC. Can someone tell me what should and all I need to take care?

[image]

Comment: Can’t you just use a voltage divider to bring your 70 V down to something directly manageable?

Comment: @winny, that +70V is from a different supply. This is not part of the PCB. Whereas, the op-amp and the +3.3V is present on the PCB.

Comment: How are the grounds related?

Comment: Isolation has a very specific meaning here- galvanic isolation. If you don't need isolation (just to reduce the voltage and the 70V has - or can have- a common ground) then the solution will be much cheaper, more accurate (likely) and simpler. It's also likely simpler and cheaper to create an isolated 3.3V supply than to try to isolate an analog signal accurately. Speaking of which, what is the accuracy target?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you for the comment. So, just a voltage divider will help with the isolation? Also, the accuracy target is 0.5%

Comment: It's not clear whether you need galvanic isolation or not. More information is required.

Comment: You didn’t answer my question. How are the grounds of your opamp supply and your input signal supply related? Are they the same, if not, why and how much isolation do you need?

Answer (score 2):

More information is required on whether you need galvanic isolation.

If you don't, resistive dividers should be fine.

If you do, then I would be tempted to have the whole of the ADC circuit on the HV side (powered in that domain) with a logic level isolator on the digital interface (e.g. SPI).

The approach of high-siding the ADC avoids the need for linear, potentially high bandwidth, isolation circuits (which can be tricky), and instead only needs a digital isolator.

There are lots of isolators specifically designed for this purpose, including ones with isolated PSUs (if needed).